# Why do I get a syntax error using the ternary operator?

Tags: ruby, ternary-operator

I wrote an if-then-else program, but when changing the code to use the ternary operator I am getting a syntax error and cannot figure out why it will not work:

```
def are_you_over_21
  puts"How old are you?"
  age = gets.chomp.to_i
  age>=21 ? puts"You're over 21!" : puts"You're too young."
end

are_you_over_21
```

Comment: What is the exact syntax error? Ruby will tell you what line is generating it, and knowing that helps us help you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll have to think about the Ruby parser.

This will work fine:

```
age >= 21 ? puts("You're over 21!") : puts("You're too young.")
```

The reason is that if you use the `puts` method without brackets, the parser doesn't understand the `:` token that comes afterwards; it doesn't realise that it is associated with the ternary operator earlier. You can also do this:

```
puts age >= 21 ? "You're over 21!" : "You're too young."
```

This is fine -- the parser doesn't run into any ambiguities here.

You can also do this:

```
puts "You're #{ age >= 21 ? 'over 21!' : 'too young.' }"
```

Here's why the ambiguity happens. Let's say you have two functions, `x` and `a`, like this:

```
2.0.0-p195 :033 > def x(y)
2.0.0-p195 :034?>   y + 1
2.0.0-p195 :035?>   end
 => nil 
2.0.0-p195 :036 > def a(b)
2.0.0-p195 :037?>   b + 2
2.0.0-p195 :038?>   end
 => nil
```

The brackets don't make a difference here:

```
2.0.0-p195 :039 > x a 1
 => 4 
2.0.0-p195 :040 > x a(1)
 => 4 
2.0.0-p195 :041 > x(a(1))
 => 4 
2.0.0-p195 :042 > x(a 1)
 => 4
```

But if `x` could take more than one parameter? Now you have to help the parser out:

```
2.0.0-p195 :043 > def x(y, z)
2.0.0-p195 :044?>   y + z + 1
2.0.0-p195 :045?>   end
```

Let's make a call without brackets like before:

```
2.0.0-p195 :047 > x a 1, 2
```

Are you passing `a(1), 2` to `x`, or are you trying to call `a(1, 2)` and pass the result to `x`? By convention Ruby assumes you are trying to call `a(1, 2)`, but `a` only takes one argument, so you get an error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
  from (irb):36:in `a'
```

So you need brackets:

```
2.0.0-p195 :052 > x a(1), 2
 => 6
```

Comment: This is an excellent response and also an irb/mri gem for newbs looking to understand some of Ruby's internals.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
age>=21 ? puts("You're over 21!") : puts("You're too young.")
```

The ternary operator gets confused when the given options have function calls without the parenthesis.

You can also do this:

```
puts age>=21 ? "You're over 21!" : "You're too young."
```

Answer (score 1):

Better than doing the unconditional `puts` in the ternary, which is a conditional statement, why not `puts` the result of the ternary?

```
def are_you_over_21                                
  puts"How old are you?"                           
  age = gets.to_i                                  
  age >= 21 ? "You're over 21!" : "You're too young."
end                                                

puts are_you_over_21
```

Also, it isn't an error, but the nature of a number (Integer in your case) means that it will never need a `chomp`, as numbers do not have new lines.  You never need to use `chomp.to_i` or `chomp.to_f`.

Notice that the method now returns an instance of `String`, rather than nil.  It can now be used as you would like, in this case, using `puts` to display to the terminal.

Spaces around the comparison operator makes it easier to read.

The method itself may as well not be a method if you are going to prompt, get data, and report.  You would be doing just as well to remove the method definition and just have this as running code.

I have refactored this to be that way:

```
def are_you_over_21(age)
  age >= 21 ? "You're over 21!" : "You're too young."
end

[18, 20, 21, 22, 100].each do |age|
  puts are_you_over_21(age)
end

# >> You're too young.
# >> You're too young.
# >> You're over 21!
# >> You're over 21!
# >> You're over 21!
```

Hope that helps.